# How to install Stackage as the system default?

Tags: haskell, cabal, stackage

The installation instructions at the [Stackage web site](https://www.stackage.org/) describe how to use it for one project.

Is there a way how to configure Stackage to be the default for all users and install packages globally available to them?

Comment: can't you just set `remote-repo` in `~/.cabal/config`?

Comment: @ibotty Yes, but I'm interested in making it the default for all users, in particular I need to avoid any changes in `~/.cabal`.

Comment: Ah, I see. The other "global". I assumed you meant not in a sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK cabal does not support a global config file. But even that won't help by itself because afaict, you can't disable configured `remote-repo`s anyway.

So I see two approaches with obvious drawbacks.

### Clean way for new users

Install a `/etc/skel/.cabal/config` file that will be copied to new user accounts. That won't help with older users though.

### Hacky way for all users

Install a global alias (or shell script wrapper) with name `cabal` that calls `cabal --remote-repo=hackage.haskell.org:http://www.stackage.org/lts`.

Users can opt out by `unalias`ing cabal or using the real cabal executable when using a shell script.

Users will be utterly confused though, because cabal will tell users it uses hackage, when in fact it is using stackage.